# Styled-Component Project Structure and multiple index.js files

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I see alot of projects using the following structure.

```
src
├── App
│   ├── Header
│   │   ├── Logo.js    
│   │   ├── Title.js   
│   │   ├── Subtitle.js
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── Footer
│       ├── List.js
│       ├── ListItem.js
│       ├── Wrapper.js
│       └── index.js
```

What is the use or benefit of those index.js files inside every Folder?

Comment: Technically you are separating into different components the `Header` and `Footer` inside `App`.

Comment: Yes I got that, but of what use are thoose index.js files?

Comment: @JangoCG did my answer help? let me know if you need more clarity

Comment: Yes it did! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JangoCG glad to help. have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally in this context the `index` file will be used to export stuff from all the other files

like this:

```
export * from './Logo'
export * from './Title'
export * from './Subtitle'
```

that way you can `import { Logo, Title, SubTitle } from '/App/Header`

instead of having to individually `import` them all from their separate file paths or include the extension on the end like so: `import { Logo } from '/App/Header/Logo.js`